# ASP.NET MVC 5 Project Load Failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Up until yesterday, I was able to open and create ASP.NET MVC 5 web application in VS 2015 Update 2. Since then, I can no longer open existing MVC 5 projects of create new ones. I did not manually update VS 2015.

Here are some example errors I am getting:

C:\Projects\Samples\xxxx\xxxx.xproj : error  : Import "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.ProjectSystem.UnconfiguredWebProject.IdleScheduler" could not be satisfied.

C:\Projects\Samples\xxxx\xxxx.xproj : error  : Instantiated part(s) threw exception(s) from IDisposable.Dispose().

Any ideas on the cause and solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was an extension called Productivity Power Tools 2015. Once disabled, I was able to load my projects.